# My jquery scroll to elements works in firefox, safari but not in chrome for some reason

Tags: jquery, scroll

```
$(document.body).ready(function() {
$('.js--nav-icon').click(function() {
        var nav = $('.js--main-nav');
        var icon = $('.js--nav-icon i');
        nav.slideToggle(200);
        if (icon.hasClass('ion-navicon-round')) {
            icon.addClass('ion-close-round');
            icon.removeClass('ion-navicon-round');
        } else {
            icon.addClass('ion-navicon-round');
            icon.removeClass('ion-close-round');
        }
    });
/*--scroll-to-on-click--*/
    $('.js--scroll-to-contact-us').click(function () {
       $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.js--section-contact-us').offset().top}, 1000);
    });
    $('.js--scroll-to-services').click(function () {
       $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.js--section-services').offset().top}, 1000);
    });
```

});

I obviously have assigned the js--section services to correct spots otherwise it wouldnt work in firefox

Comment: Have you tried with `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Yes thanks originally , i then updated my chrome and it solved the problem. wish i knew how to get around this as come visitors to my site may have older browsers